# Is there a way to programmatically let a UILabel determine its intrinsic content size

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have created a label via and a container view via:

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50))
label.text = "omnomnom"
let labelView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100))
labelView.addSubview(label)
labelView.bringSubviewToFront(label)
labelView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
label.textAlignment = .Center
```

But the label text might change so as a result for a longer word the whole thing won't be shown. I was wondering whether there is way to determine the intrinsic content size after the label is added, so that I can use those values to create a container view that is just a little bit bigger than that of the label.

Comment: Do you want to use auto layout constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sizeToFit` to accomplish that. So you only need to add `label.sizeToFit()` to the end of your label configuration.